# Submit form & prevent modal from closing

Tags: php, jquery, forms, modal-dialog

I have my registration form in a hand-made modal window.
When click on submit, if the form contains errors it fires up a new modal-window on top of that, which displays the  php error messages.

When closing that "errors modal window" --> I get back to my form which now is supposed to have its incorrectly filled fiels labels red...

All of my js, style & php are done, I just need to understand how to submit the form without auto-closing my windows.

```
 $('#submit_signUp').click(function( event ) {  event.preventDefault(); });
```

If the form isn't submitted and thats' not what I am looking for...

Comment: use ajax to send the data to server. check for the expected result. if it is correct hide the modal or keep the modal as it is

Comment: Okay, if there's no other way, I'm gonna try that.

 Thanks for your fast answer. :)